# django - insert value into a text filed using javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I have a django form on my template like this:

```
<form action="/my-page/" method="post" name="my_form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.txt_filed1.errors }}
        <label for="id_txt_field1">Profile Name:</label>
        {{ form.txt_filed1 }}
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" name='update_button' value="Update" /></p>
</form>
```

I've been trying to insert a value to a text filed  above using javascript but I didn't have much success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
document.my_form.form-txt_filed1.value = "my value";
</script>
```

Any idea what might be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark but try changing the script to `document.my_form.txt_filed1.value = "my value";`

Comment: what's the HTML output of that Django code?

Comment: The html output of the django code is: <input id="id_form-txt_filed1" type="text" name="form-txt_field1" maxlength="60" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you put `form-` in when your field doesn't contain that.

Try:

```
// by the way, do you notice that your label is for id_txt_field1
// while your form field says {{ form.txt_filed1 }} ? 
document.my_form.txt_filed1.value = "my value";
```

Or:

```
document.getElementById('id_txt_filed_1').value = 'hello';
```

---

Or pick up a javascript framework. I prefer writing in jQuery:

```
$("input[name=txt_field_1]").val("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

added id to the form

```
<form action="/my-page/" method="post" id="my_form" name="my_form">{% csrf_token %}
....
</form>
```

then in the js code

```
//initialized form as a variable and then set properties
var my_form = document.getElementById("my_form");
my_form.txt_filed1.value = "my value";
```